# how to create a object from interface in typescript angular application

Tags: angular, typescript

We have a nested interface pasted a portion of it below , it has more fields may be 25 more some are nested
how we can generate a object in angular application from a type script,

do we really need to duplicate the same field and create a class?

in c# we can do like var account = new Account();

is there a way like this can be done in typescript with out assigning any values to fields like address or do i need to make all the fields nullable for this?

and later we can do it by assigning later.

```
 export interface Account {
accountID: string
address: Address[]
accountType: string
user:User
```

}

```
   export interface Address {
line1: string
line2: string
line3: string
suburb: string
postcode: string
state: string
countryCode: string
phone:string
```

}

```
 export interface User {
firstName: string
lastName: string
title: string
}
```